# Webpack "Unexpected token export" when trying to use the "framer-motion" module

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, next.js

I am using NextJS and until now I had no problems using it.
After I installed the "framer-motion" module for animating some of my components, whenever I try to visit the page which contains the import statement:

```js
import { motion } from "framer-motion"
```

NextJS instead of rendering the page throws an error:

And presents me with the code snippet:

```
Unexpected token 'export'

Source

external%20%22framer-motion%22 (1:0) @ eval

> 1 | module.exports = require("framer-motion");
```

If I go into the terminal this is the error I get:

```
export { MotionConfig, MotionConfigContext } from './context/MotionConfigContext.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

If I take out the import statement, it's rendering the page as intended

Another thing that I accidentally noticed is, if I don't include the import statement before rendering the page for the first time, then after it renders I include it, NextJS will hot-reload the page and when that happens the import statement isn't causing any issues and I could animate my components.
The animation works too. So I presume I have to configure something with Webpack or Babel?
I have never used either Babel or Webpack so I don't know

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this works for me:

```
import { motion } from 'framer-motion/dist/framer-motion'
```

I don't understand why, if anyone could fill me in that would be great!

Comment: It's probably because they recently changed `framer-motion` to be exported as ESM, meaning it would need to be transpiled before using it in Next.js. While using `framer-motion/dist/framer-motion` probably points to the CJS exports.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my ./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/components/AnimatePresence/index.mjs Can't import the named export 'Children' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) error!